# Configure Sequelize.js to throw EmptyResultError on findById() but resolve [] if findAll() is empty

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Is there a way to configure Sequelize globally so that:

- `Model.findById(id)` throws `EmptyResultError`
- `Model.findAll()` resolves with `[]`

I've tried the following config but this makes `findAll` return an `EmptyResultError` too:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(null, null, null, {
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'tmp/db.sqlite',
  define: { rejectOnEmpty: true }
})
```

I'm looking for a global config so that all Models behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like there's a way to change how `rejectOnEmpty` config behaves but I was able to extend the `Model` prototype with the function I was after.

```
Sequelize.Model.find = async function (...args) {
  const obj = await this.findById(...args)
  if (obj === null) throw Boom.notFound()

  return obj
}
```